# Installing Asterisk 15.1.2 on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, asterisk, freepbx

I have installed Asterisk 15.1.2 and it is running.
When i try to install FreePBX 14.0, i am getting an error as shown:

[root@localhost freepbx]# ./start_asterisk start

STARTING ASTERISK
Asterisk is already running
[root@localhost freepbx]# ./install -n
Assuming you are Database Root
Checking if SELinux is enabled...Its not (good)!
Reading /etc/asterisk/asterisk.conf...Done
Checking if Asterisk is running and we can talk to it as the 'asterisk' user...Error!
Error communicating with Asterisk.  Ensure that Asterisk is properly installed and running as the asterisk user
Asterisk appears to be running as root
Try starting Asterisk with the './start_asterisk start' command in this directory
[root@localhost freepbx]#

Can someone help me in fixing this. I have to access the PBX GUI.

Answer (score -1):

Freepbx installation manual clearly state, asterisk SHOULD NOT be runned.

So before freepbx install script do

```
asterisk -rx "core stop now"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Asterisk appears to be running as root
```

It should be running as asterisk user.